# Changing id of one of the module titles having same id joomla

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I have these three modules all with same id:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('user2')) : ?>
    <div id="user2-wrap"><div id="user2" class="container row clr">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="usergrid" grid="<?php echo $user2_width; ?>" />
    </div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And upon inspecting i get:

```
    <div id="user2-wrap"><div id="user2" class="container row clr">
                    <div class="module   span_4 col clr">
                <h3 class="module-title">Our Story</h3>
            <div class="module-body"> 
    <div class="custom">

<div id="user2-wrap"><div id="user2" class="container row clr">
                    <div class="module   span_4 col clr">
                <h3 class="module-title">Featured Training</h3>
            <div class="module-body"> 
    <div class="custom">


<div id="user2-wrap"><div id="user2" class="container row clr">
                    <div class="module   span_4 col clr">
                <h3 class="module-title">Chapters</h3>
            <div class="module-body"> 
    <div class="custom">
```

All these have same class `module-title` i need to change the color of one `module-title`. How can i change id of one specific `module-title`? or are there any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the nth-child solution with your `module-title` class.

```
:nth-child(number_of_the_child_you_want_to_change) {
   your css declarations;
}
```

Here is the link [CSS nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

EDIT: If you want/can use JavaScript, use this code to select the second element in the document with `class="module-title"`.

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('.module-title')[1].style.color = "red";
</script>
```

I changed the text color, ofc you need to insert your own changes to the class element.

Comment: i got the hint. but it's not working. upon inspecting `.module-title:nth-child(2)` is disabled.

Comment: I guess then you stumbled upon the problem that the elements are nested. If you can use JavaScript or JQuery, you could select the elements dynamically.

Comment: I added the JavaScript solution to your post. Here is the fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wsym1goe/)